# where does the Intellij IDE store the artifacts settings of one project

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, war

I am using Git in Intellij. Every time I change git branch, my artifacts settings is gone, so I have to reset the settings. 
I want to get the file which stores the artifacts settings, So I can put the file in when I switch the branch to avoid resetting the artifacts.
I wonder if there is a file storing the artifacts settings.

Another question btw, I want to package a war in Intellij, but the automatic way always lose some files, so I set the artifacts manually. I wonder if there is one way to package the war better.

Thanks for your any suggestion or help.

Comment: Maybe you can write the artifacts packaging conf to maven conf

Comment: What is the name and location of this file?

Comment: How are you managing your libraries?  Through Maven or Gradle?  (If you're not using one of those options, you're going to be in for a world of pain, as you may realize.)

Comment: `.idea/artifacts` directory, see also https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839.

Comment: @CrazyCoder That's it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The settings are stored in `.idea/artifacts` directory (inside the project root directory). You may [consider sharing it via the version control](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839).

Comment: I have the same situation, but I cannot share the .idea dir becuse I'm the only team member using intellij IDEA. What would be the solution for me?

Answer (score 1):

You can put war file by:
Go Project Structure -> Artifacts -> choose Output Directory.